# UICollectionView reuseIdentifier in sizeForItemAtIndexPath - swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, reuseidentifier

I have the following code, which puts a collection view into either one or two columns, depending the size of the screen:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let size = collectionView.frame.width
    if (size > 500) {
        return CGSize(width: (size/2) - 8, height: (size/2) - 8)
    }
    return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
}
```

I would like to amend this, so the height is dependent upon the reuseIdentifier. There are two I use - set something like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let diceRoll = Int(arc4random_uniform(2) + 1)
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("profileViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    if(diceRoll == 1) {
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("profileChartViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    }
    return cell
}
```

How can I get the reuseIndentifier of the current cell, so that I can change the height depending on what type of cell it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reuseIdentifier` is a property of `UICollectionViewReusableView`, which is `UICollectionViewCell`'s base class.  Thus you can call `cell.reuseIdentifier` at any time once you have a cell.

I'm not sure what your notion of "current cell" is.  You can ask the collection view for a given cell at an index path with `collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath()`, and you can track which cell is currently selected by implementing the delegate method `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` and then saving off the currently selected indexPath.

Alternately (and what I'd recommend) is that you either subclass `UICollectionViewCell` and have the subclassed cell be responsible for its own height, or implement a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` class and handle size there.

If you implement your own cell subclasses, be sure to call `registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` on your custom cell so the `UICollectionView` knows how to create it properly.